# How can I resolve TypeError with StringIO in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, stringio

Trying to read following string as file using `StringIO` but getting the error below. How can I resolve it?

```
>> from io import StringIO
>>>
>>> datastring = StringIO("""\
... Country  Metric           2011   2012   2013  2014
... USA     GDP               7      4     0      2
... USA     Pop.              2      3     0      3
... GB      GDP               8      7     0      7
... GB      Pop.              2      6     0      0
... FR      GDP               5      0     0      1
... FR      Pop.              1      1     0      5
... """)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 9, in <module>
TypeError: initial_value must be unicode or None, not str
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can resolve the error by simply adding a u before your string to make the string unicode:

```
datastring = StringIO(u"""\
Country  Metric           2011   2012   2013  2014
USA     GDP               7      4     0      2
USA     Pop.              2      3     0      3
GB      GDP               8      7     0      7
GB      Pop.              2      6     0      0
FR      GDP               5      0     0      1
FR      Pop.              1      1     0      5
""")
```

Your initial value [should be unicode](http://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.StringIO).

Answer (score 14):

Rather use (fixes this exact issue for me):

```
from StringIO import StringIO
```

Comment: I converted my codes to python2.7 from python3.6, forgot the import statement as from io import StringIO I have remembered when I see this

Comment: For Python3 i can not use 'from StringIO'. In my case 'from io import BytesIO' was working

Comment: Indeed - but the OP is labelled python-2.x @TobiasZanke

Comment: The whole topic is a minefield :-\