# Plotting 2 variables in Python from an Excel file

Tags: python, pandas

I am a Python beginner. I want to start learning Python with plotting.

I would really appreciate if someome can help me write a script to plot an Excel file with 2 variables (velocity, and direction) below:

```
Date            Velocity    Direction
3/12/2011 0:00  1.0964352   10
3/12/2011 0:30  1.1184975   15
3/12/2011 1:00  0.48979592  20
3/12/2011 1:30  0.13188942  45
```

Answer (score 1):

Prepare the data

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = '''\
Date            Velocity    Direction 
3/12/2011 0:00  1.0964352   10 
3/12/2011 0:30  1.1184975   15 
3/12/2011 1:00  0.48979592  20 
3/12/2011 1:30  0.13188942  45
'''
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep=r'\s{2,}', parse_dates=[0], dayfirst=True)
```

I use a trick here. Because the Dates in the `Date` column contain time elements, that are separated by a single whitespace, I separate columns by two or more whitespaces. This is why I give the separator as a regex `sep=r'\s{2,}'`. But of course in a CSV columns are normally separated by a comma which makes things easier (`sep=','` which is the default setting).

Note that the `Date` column has been parsed as dates. Its column type is `datetime64`.

```
df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 4 entries, 0 to 3
Data columns (total 3 columns):
Date         4 non-null datetime64[ns]
Velocity     4 non-null float64
Direction    4 non-null int64
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(1), int64(1)
memory usage: 176.0 bytes
```

By setting the `Date` column as the index plotting the data is simple:

```
df.set_index('Date').plot()
```

This will result in a line plot where both velocity and direction are plotted for each timestamp.

[image: Plot]

Comment: you might add the imports, just to make it obvious.

Comment: @gregory Thanks for the hint. I added them.

Comment: Thanks a lot. However, I got an error:                                                                                                             df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep=r'\s{2,}', parse_dates=[0], dayfirst=True)        Do you know why?
TypeError: initial_value must be unicode or None, not str

Comment: I guess you're using Python 2.7. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22316333/how-can-i-resolve-typeerror-with-stringio-in-python-2-7

Comment: Oh and by the way I use `StringIO` for demo purposes only. There is no need to copy the plain data from your XLS sheet to python and use `StringIO`. You can use [`read_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) instead. Please see the docs for pandas file IO methods.